# How to change the size of legend box in Plotly?

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, legend

It is my code below:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go


fig = go.Figure()

for i in range(100):
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=[1,2],
        y=[1,2],
        name = f'{i}'*20,
        showlegend=True
    ))

fig.update_layout(
    autosize=True,
    minreducedheight=450,
    legend=dict(orientation="h",yanchor="bottom",y=1.02,xanchor="left",x=0,font=dict(size=10),itemwidth=30),
)


fig.show()
```

Legend and main figure will be overlaid.
I would like to reduce the height of legend, so that it will not overlay with main figure.

Answer (score 1):

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go


fig = go.Figure()

for i in range(100):
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=[1,2],
        y=[1,2],
        name = f'{i}'*20,
        showlegend=True
    ))

fig.update_layout(
    autosize=True,
    # try to play around height and width values 
    height=450,
    width=50,
legend=dict(orientation="h",yanchor="bottom",y=1.02,xanchor="left",x=0,font=dict(size=10),itemwidth=30),
)

fig.show()
```

**you can find some helpful examples in this link** : https://plotly.com/python/legend/